# サーバのOracleClientが、目的の.NET FrameworkのVerを有していない場合の対応

Tags: asp.net

WindowsServer2012R2 64bitに、現在Oracleクライアントがインストールされているのですが
DOS窓からSQLPLUSを実行したら11.2.0.1というVerが表示されました。

当該サーバでASP.NET4.0（.NET Framework 4.0）のサイトを運用しだそうと考えていますが

OracleDataAccessの収まったフォルダを確認すると（ODP.NET）．．．2xというフォルダしか
見当たらない状況です。

自分の要望を達成する上で「4」というフォルダが存在していれば　話しが早かった認識ですが
現況からして、どういう解決策があるのかご教示を頂けますでしょうか？

【質問の背景】
当該サーバで複数のVerのOracleClientがインストールされた状態の運用を不安視している。
既存の利用機能（当該期はMSSQLServerを運用中。現行プロバイダをリンクサーバ機能で利用中）
に災いが生じないか　心配になったため　ご見解をうかがいたく。

【思いついている案・いづれか】
①開発端末からサーバにサイトを移行する際、4.0版OracleDataAccessのみをBINフォルダに収めて配置
②開発端末のOracleCleintに見えている「4」というフォルダを、サーバのODP.NETフォルダに格納してしまう。
③.NET Framework 4.0のODP.NETを同梱のOracleClientを新たに入手し、目的のサーバにインストールする。
（どういった事を懸念しなければならないのか不明なので教えて欲しい）

よろしくお願い致します。

追加
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 書き方の問題ですが「見える」とか感想を述べるのではなく具体的な事実を列挙してください。よくわかりませんがファイルのプロパティにはバージョン番号が記載されていませんか？

Comment: ODP.NET\BINのフォルダに「2X」のフォルダしかなく、「4」のフォルダがありません。
存在している.NetFrameWork2.0用と思われるOracleDataAccessのVerは追加した画像のとおり2.112.1.0です。
ご期待に沿う回答になっていますでしょうか

Comment: 所望のバージョンがインストールされているかどうかはそのサーバの管理者の責任であって、説明としては蛇足に感じます(インストールしていないものが勝手に入っているはずが無いし、入っていないならインストールするしかない)。それらを踏まえて質問としては「複数バージョンが共有できるか」と「(インストールを経ずに)ファイルのコピーだけで動くか」という事ですよね？

Comment: 恥ずかしながら仰られるとおりです...いや本当に。

Comment: Oracle Database (サーバー側)のバージョンは何ですか？質問の趣旨とは外れますが、古くなければManagedDriverも選択肢に入ります。

Comment: 2筐体ありまして双方ASP.NETでの接続を希望しており
11.2.0.4.0と11.2.0.1.0です。